# I keep getting path error when i input in the django app

Tags: python, django

this is my views.py, when i input in anything i get error i tried changing the path to /fo still there is error...................
this is the test.py ````import sys
import datetime
time = datetime.datetime.now()
output = "hi" % (sys.argv[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxmYA.png), time)
print(output)```

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import requests
import sys
from subprocess import run, PIPE




def button(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html')


def output(request):

    data = requests.get("https://www.google.com/")

    print(data.text)
    data = data.text
    return render(request, 'home.html', {'data': data})


def external(request):
    inp = request.POST.get('param')
    out = run([sys.executable, 'buttonpython/buttonpython/test.py',
              inp], shell=False, stdout=PIPE)
    print(out)
    return render(request, 'home.html', {'data1': out.stdout})
```

[image]

Comment: You have no path `external/` it is, according to the path patterns `fo/`.

Comment: path('external/', views.external)
]should i change it to this?

Comment: then i get TypeError at /external/
expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType

Comment: the `request.POST.get('param')` returns `None`, since you did not make a POST request (with that parameter).

Comment: doesnt it take input from home.html
<body>   <button onclick="location.href='{% url 'script' %}'">
        Execute
    </button><hr>
    {% if data %}
    {{data | safe}}
    {% endif %}
    <form action="/external/" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        Input Text:
        <input type ="text" name="param" required><br>
        <br>
        {{data_external}}<br><br>
        {{data1}}
        <input type ="submit" value="Execute External Python Script" >

    </form></body>

Comment: no, by changing the location, the browser makes a GET request. You need to use the button wrapped in the form, and use action="{% url 'script' %}".

Comment: def button(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html') i had written this twice now the page is loading but i am getti ng  b ' as the output

Comment: but i have done that  <button onclick="location.href='{% url 'script' %}'"> Execute </button>

Comment: that will trigger a **GET** request... You need to make a **POST** request to the `/fo/` path.

Comment: oh ok and  so i change this inp = request.POST.get('param')